# Como restaurar o backup feito com SMO?

Tags: c#

Preciso fazer um backup e restaurar usando SMO.
O backup consigo fazer, agora quando seleciono ele no combobox digitando o nome do servidor e do database da erro. Segue o código do botão restore:

```
   private void restauracaoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var server = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(servidorTextBox.Text);
            var restore = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore();
            restore.Database = databaseTextBox.Text;
            restore.Devices.AddDevice(backupsComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString(), Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DeviceType.File);
            server.KillAllProcesses(databaseTextBox.Text);
            restore.SqlRestore(server);
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Backup '{0}' restaurado com sucesso.", backupsComboBox.Text), "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

vou postar o print do erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual erro que da?

Comment: Postei logo acima Dener. Pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Vc postou a rotina que efetua a restauração do banco.

Comment: Em qual linha que recebes o erro?

Comment: seguinte erro é postado quando clico no botão restaurar backup :

An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll

Comment: postei Dener o print do erro

Comment: Capture esta exceção no try catch, e poste a mensagem de erro.

Comment: vou fazer um momento

Comment: mostra o mesmo erro

Comment: editei a pergunta com o print do erro Dener

Comment: @user37846 edite a pergunta com o StackTrace da excepção e coloque também a InnerException (mensagem e StackTrace).

Comment: não sei fazer isso

Comment: Na janela que aparece com a excepcao (como mostra na sua imagem), carregue em "View Detail...", na janela que aparece tem la a mensagem, stack trace e inner exception.

Comment: não sei fazer isso

Comment: Em vez de continuar a dizer que nao sabe, aconselhava que desse uma vista de olhos [nesse tutorial que ensina a lidar com excepcoes no Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/x85tt0dd.aspx).

Comment: ao invés de ficar me indicando para reorganizar minha pergunta e minhas imagens , poderia me ajudar de uma vez!

Comment: @user37846 entenda que para o podermos ajudar precisamos de entender qual o problema. Existem vários motivos pelo qual o backup pode estar a falhar a linha que esta a falhar, portanto sem mais informação de depuração, vai ficar complicado ajuda-lo.

Comment: @user37846 é importante organizar a sua pergunta, tente se colocar no lugar de quem vai responder, é preciso para a comunidade poder ajudar vc.